# Index is outside bounds of array

Tags: c#

When I run this it says that index was outside of bounds for the array but it is not.
If I change public static ConectorRec[] ch = new ConectorRec[74]; to ConectorRec[] ch = new ConectorRec[75]; then they are not all referenced to an object and throws other errors on other parts of my code.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Dots
{
    public static class Conectors
    {
        public static ConectorRec[] ch = new ConectorRec[74];
        public static void intitialize()
        {
            ch[0] = new ConectorRec(new Rectangle(10, 20, 10, 40));
            ch[1] = new ConectorRec(new Rectangle(20, 10, 40, 10));
            ch[2] = new ConectorRec(new Rectangle(20, 60, 40, 10));
            ch[3] = new ConectorRec(new Rectangle(60, 20, 10, 40));
            int t = 0;
            int tt = 1;
            for (int i = 4; i<73; i++)
            {
                t++;
                if (t == 1)
                {
                    ch[i] = new ConectorRec(new Rectangle(50 * tt + 20, 10, 40, 10));
                }
                if (t == 2)
                {
                    ch[i] = new ConectorRec(new Rectangle(50 * tt + 20, 60, 40, 10));
                }
                if (t == 3)
                {
                    tt++;
                    ch[i] = new ConectorRec(new Rectangle(50 * tt + 10, 20, 10, 40));
                    t = 0;
                }
            }
            ch[74] = new ConectorRec(new Rectangle(10, 70, 10, 40));
        }
    }
}
```

please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this error.

Comment: `please tell me what I am doing wrong` - you seem to be using winforms.

Comment: i got it to work i had to test where my loop was ending off in and then had to make the index bigger like everybody said

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When I run this it says that index was outside of bounds for the array but it is not

Yes it is. Even if I couldn't pinpoint the problem, I'd always bet on the runtime being more accurate than the developer's opinion on this...

This is the problem, after the loop:

```
ch[74] = new ConnectorRec(...);
```

You've declared the array to have 74 elements here:

```
public static ConectorRec[] ch = new ConectorRec[74];
```

So the valid indexes are 0..73 inclusive. If you want to make 74 a valid index, you need to declare it to have *75* elements:

```
public static ConectorRec[] ch = new ConectorRec[75];
```

Answer (score 4):

Array indices are *zero-based*.Your array size is `74` so your last element is `ch[73]` not `74`. You can verify that by using [`GetUpperBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var maxIndex = ch.GetUpperBound(0); // this will return 73
```

From C# Specification [`Section 12. Arrays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664484%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The length of a dimension determines the valid range of indices for that dimension: For a dimension of length **N**, indices can range from 0 to **N – 1 inclusive**.

In this case your array Length (N) is `74` and therefore max. index is `73` (N -1).

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to

```
ch[74] = new ConectorRec(new Rectangle(10, 70, 10, 40));
```

Your array size is `74` that means you will have the maximum index of `73`, **since array index starts from `0`**